# Won't display more than one value

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

There is no error but I was expecting 10 values but I only got one. The below is my create and display function.

```
void create()
{
int random;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    struct node *new_node, *current;
    new_node = new node;
    random = randomNum();
    new_node->data = random;
    new_node->next = NULL;
    if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = new_node;
        current = new_node;
        new_node = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        current->next = new_node;
        current = new_node;
    }
 }
}

void display()
{
struct node *new_node;
new_node = start;
while (new_node != NULL)
{
    cout << new_node->data << "->";
    new_node = new_node->next;
}
}
```

What do I need to change?

Comment: If start isn't NULL, where does current get initialized?

Comment: _I tried initializing `current->next = NULL`_ Did you read the warning message? It is complaining about `current` (which isn't initialized), not `current->next`. And the reason for such a warning is: if condition in `if (start == NULL)` is false - `else` block is executed, and `current->next = new_node;` is UB due to a dereference of uninitialized pointer (your attempted fix of `current->next = NULL` is UB for the same reason).

Comment: @Wing Hang Khoo Is it an indeed error or a warning? If it is a warning you may ignore it.

Comment: First of all, what is `start`? I can't see it declared anywhere. Secondly, every time `start` is not NULL you're using `current` when it's uninitialized - `current->next = new_node`. So the compiler is absolutely right.

Comment: @Steve start was initialized as NULL in the start.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow it's an error.

Comment: @WingHangKhoo I didn't ask about `start`, I asked about `current`

Comment: @VladfromMoscow until you enable the 'treat warnings as errors' flag... ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following line

```
current = new_node;    
current->next = new_node;
```

Because in your case there is no value of  `current` pointer so how can you update its next. First of all update/set the current then update/set its next.

```
if (start == NULL)
    {
        start = new_node;
        current = new_node;
        current->next = NULL;
        new_node = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        current = new_node;
        current->next = new_node;

    }
```

Comment: There is no error now, but my output is not displayed properly. What do I need to change?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with the compiler message is that the compiler is unable to determine whether the variable `current` used in the else statement was early initialized.

If it is a warning you may ignore it.

Or you can rewrite the function the following way

```
void create()
{
    const int N = 10;

    node **current = &start;

    while ( *current ) current = &( *current )->next;

    for ( int i = 0; i < N; i++ )
    {
        *current = new node;
        ( *current )->data = randomNum();
        ( *current )->next = nullptr;
        current = &( *current )->next;
    }
 }
```

The body of the for loop can be also written like (I assume that the data member `data` precedes the data member `next` in the node definition. Otherwise exchange the initializers.

```
*current = new node { randomNum(), nullptr };
current = &( *current )->next;
```